# Angular bootstrap Carousel- How to move to next image of ng-bootstrap carousel in an angular component?

Tags: angular, carousel, ng-bootstrap

I am using ng-bootstrap plugin with Angular 7 to create a carousel.
Following is the HTML:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" (slide)="onSlide($event)">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
    <img [src]="image" alt="Random slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>{{image.id}}</h3>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

I have the onSlide function in my component as:

```
onSlide(e){
 if(/*Some condition*/){
    //how to move to next image here?
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the comment, in the onSlide function, I want to move to next image based on some condition. How to move to next image in the if condition there?

I referenced [official documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/api#NgbCarousel) by the ng-bootstarap. They have mentioned next() method there. But I am sure how to use that one. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get a template reference from `ngb-carousel`, and give it to `onSlide` function:

```
<ngb-carousel #caro *ngIf="images" (slide)="onSlide($event, caro)">
```

call `caro.next()` on certain condition:

```
onSlide(e, caro){
  if(/*Some condition*/){
    caro.next()
  }
}
```

Be careful it could fall in infinite loop since `next()` invoke a `(slide)` event.